# Save Array Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I can't save an array of strings into my DB using Mongoose

The schema:

```
const TrombinoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: [String]
});

const Trombino = mongoose.model('Trombino', TrombinoSchema);
```

and for save:

```
var trombino = new Trombino ({
    Name: req.query.name
});

trombino.save(callback);

Array.isArray(req.query.name) => true;
```

I tried different statement

```
 Name: [{type : String}] , Name: [{type : String}] or Name: []
```

but in my DB i found the empty Array

Comment: could you show what the callback method looks like? Does it report any errors? What does `Array.isArray` is supposed to do? Did you mean `==` instead of `=>`?

Comment: for callback there is no error, trombino.save(function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(data);
  });
console.log(Array.isArray(req.query.name))
true, for testing is array or not !!

Answer (score 0):

In the trombino schema you need to change the **name field**:

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const TrombinoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {type:[String]}
  });
  const Trombino = mongoose.model('Trombino', TrombinoSchema);

  let trombinoItem = new Trombino({
    Name: ['test name 1','test name 2','test name 3']
  });
  trombinoItem.save().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Here the print of execution:

[image: Console log]

This the data in the database. You can see the **name as a array of string**:

[image]